# Spring - configuring a simple dispatcher servlet with a controller

Tags: spring, servlets

I'm new to spring and trying to configure a simple dispatcher servlet with a controller, but I can't seem to get it working.  I want going to http://localhost:8080/1/dispatcher/index to print out "welcome" in the console.  My boss says it should also automatically redirect you to index.jsp page because of the mapping.

WelcomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView welcome()
    {
        System.out.println("welcome entered");


    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dispatcher/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.paymon" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

First it seems that the indicated code does not compile. The `welcome()` method should return an object of type ModelView indicating the view to display.

In this method you can put the view to resolver, if you want show index.jsp, you put index into viewName method.